ASE GPAW variable cell relaxation
Ive been trying to do a vc relax using GPAW and ASE on the BaTiO3 unitcell. The input file is as below:
from ase.io import read, write
from ase.visualize import view
from ase.constraints import ExpCellFilter

from gpaw import GPAW
from ase.optimize import BFGS
from ase.io import read, write 
from gpaw.eigensolvers import RMMDIIS

molecule_file = 'BaTiO3.cif'
gpaw_args = dict(convergence={'eigenstates': 1e-08,
                              'density': 1e-08},
                 h=0.18, xc='PBE',parallel={"sl_auto":True},
                 eigensolver=RMMDIIS(niter=5))      





molecule = read(molecule_file)
# molecule.center(vacuum=7.0)

view(molecule)
box = ExpCellFilter(molecule)
box.calc = GPAW(**gpaw_args)

dyn = BFGS(box,trajectory='{}_T2.traj'.format(molecule_file[:-4]))
dyn.run(fmax=0.005)

But Im having the following error.
rank=07 L0: Traceback (most recent call last):
rank=07 L1:   File "/users/home/data/PZ/piezoconst/sim.py", line 33, in <module>
rank=07 L2:     box.calc = GPAW(**gpaw_args)
rank=07 L3: AttributeError: can't set attribute

Any pointers would be nice. Is it because Im not using calculator attribute properly?

you should set the calculator to the underlying molecule variable. The filter is just a wrapper around the the actual Atoms object

After some fiddling around (with the inputs from @kristof bal) I understood that the filters dont quite work with the finite difference mode of GPAW. It works perfectly with the PAW mode (given by mode=PW(cutoff)). I've attached a script below for future reference:
from ase.io import read
from ase.constraints import ExpCellFilter
from gpaw import GPAW, PW
from ase.optimize import BFGS

molecule_file = 'BaTiO3.cif'
molecule = read(molecule_file)
molecule.calc = GPAW(mode=PW(200),nbands=30,xc='PBE',gpts=(24, 24, 24))

box = ExpCellFilter(molecule)
dyn = BFGS(box)
dyn.run(fmax=0.005)

